# Spring boot - Jpa - SaveAll(Entity <S>) missing entities in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue when I am trying to save a List of 21,300 entities, however in the database only *[SELECT COUNT(id) = ] 10,506* are being saved.

The console output demonstrates the size of the list ready to be saved is correct so the code is "correct". If I make it loop only once with freq==30 for instance, this works fine so it seems linked somehow to the for each loop when it loops several times. The missing entities are somewhat dispersed in the population.

Any idea of why this particular behavior?

```
public void loadTickAll(int conid) {
    System.out.println(">>>> MERGING <<<<<< Querying ticks for " + conid);
    List<CandleTick> candlesHisto = histoCandleTickRepo.findByConidAll(conid, LocalDate.parse("2016-11-01"));
    List<CandleTick> candlesLive = new ArrayList<>();

    List<CandleTick> candles = Stream.of(candlesHisto, candlesLive).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

     freqList.forEach((freq) -> {
     if(freq>=30) {
     System.out.println("Working on freq " + freq);

     FlowMerger flowMerger = new FlowMerger(freq, contracts.get(conid));
     List<CandleMerge> flow = flowMerger.createFlow(new ArrayList<>(candles));
     Collections.reverse(flow);

     System.out.println("Start saving " + freq + " - " + flow.size());
     histoCandleMergeRepo.saveAll(flow);

     System.out.println(freq + "/" + conid + " has been delivered and saved");
     }
     });

}
```

**Console output**

`>>>> MERGING <<<<<< Querying ticks for 5 
Working on freq 30 
Start saving 30 - 21300 
30/5 has been delivered and saved`

application.properties

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

histo.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/trading2018
live.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/trading2018

jdbc.user=...
jdbc.pass=...


## hibernate.X
hibernate.default_schema=trading
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
#hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
#hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false

logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com=DEBUG
logging.file=C:/tmp/application.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to trace down the issue. I showed the SQL and noticed I was updating instead of inserting.

My entity was missing some annotations...

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "merge_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "candleid_generator_generator", sequenceName = "merge_id_seq", initialValue = 1)
@Id
private int id;
```

Comment: If this solved your question, please accept the answer by clicking in the star